# How to find this limit as $x\to 0$?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x)-\arctan(\arcsin x)}$$
Hopital's rule and Taylor expansion are practically impossible. Is there a better way to do it (mathematica gives the answer $1$). This limit is of the form $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}$$ but first $f$ and $g$ are not monotone on any neighborhood of $0$ and second how to interpret this limit graphically.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(\tan x)$ *is* monotonic in a neighborhood of $0$: it's the composition of two increasing functions.

Comment: @egreg My fault. I had $\sin(1/x)$ in my mind.

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=\sin(\tan x)$ increasing in a neighborhood of $0$? I think it is, and also $g(x)=\tan(\sin(x))$. But, how does it help with the problem?

Comment: @Wore It garanties the existence of  $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor expansion is hard but not practically impossible. Note that the functions involved are all odd. After a few computations we find that
$$\sin(\tan x)-\tan(\sin x)=-\frac{x^7}{30}+o(x^7).$$

Alternative approach.
Let $f(x)=x+ax^n+o(x^n)$ and let $g(x)=x+bx^n+o(x^n)$ with $a\not=b$. Then
$f^{-1}(x)=x-ax^n+o(x^n)$ and $g^{-1}(x)=x-bx^n+o(x^n)$. Hence
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a-b)x^n+o(x^n)}{(-b+a)x^n+o(x^n)}=1.$$
But here it is not useful because
$$f(x)=\sin(\tan x)=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\quad\mbox{and}\quad g(x)=\tan(\sin x)=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3).$$
However,[HERE](https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/lim.pdf) you can find a more general approach.

Comment: I was looking for a more intuitive way. See my edit.

Comment: @whatever See my edited answer,

Comment: Ok I see why $f^{-1}(x)=x-ax^n+o(x^n)$. $f(x)-g(x)$ is the vertical distance between the 2 curves. $g^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x)$ is the vertical distance between the symetrical curves.

Comment: @RobertZ The linked file is great!